# How do I send Order Confirmation Email after successfull Payment in Magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, frontend, order-email, payment-gateway, magento2.3.0

I am struggling with this from past 3 weeks and tried almost all of the solutions suggested but nothing works for me. I want to send an Order Confirmation email after successful payment (Payment Gateway Paystack).

Even I have tried this https://meetanshi.com/blog/send-magento-2-order-confirmation-email-after-payment-success/ but the mails stop working for an order previously emails were sent with payment now they are not. Please help how can I fix this in Magento 2.3.0.

Environment Using -

- Magento 2.3.0
- PHP 7.1
- CentOS 7 Godaddy server

Comment: you want to send default email or email using a custom template on successful payment?

Comment: @Mustafa please paste your code in your question because might be it will helpful  to answer your question.

Comment: ThanQ for the reply I have solved this issue it was my payment Gateway issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue was with my Payment gateway. I have modified the PayStack code and on successful payment, I have sent the order confirmation email. and it's working now.